# add column with default in lhm (Large Hadron Migrator)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soundcloud, database-migration

I tried to add column with default value like

```
Lhm.change_table :recomendations do |m|
  m.add_column :amount, "TINYINT", default: 1
end
```

but got error: wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2) gems/lhm-2.2.0/lib/lhm/migrator.rb:55:in `add_column'

what the correct code should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just realized it's just appending string to sql, just add default, not null etc like SQL

```
m.add_column :amount, "TINYINT DEFAULT 1"
```